# Cannot connect to azure VM. CredSSP issue

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

After I received a windows [update](http://blog.fmsinc.com/remote-desktop-authentication-error-function-requested-is-not-supported-credssp/) on my PC I cannot connect to my azure vm via RDP. How can I connect to Azure in order to install the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue.

> **Root Cause Analysis**
>
> To resolve a vulnerability issue with Credential Security Support
>   Provider protocol (CredSSP), a monthly Windows update in May was
>   applied which does two things:
>
> 1. Correct how Credential Security Support Provider protocol (CredSSP) validates requests during the authentication process
> 2. Change the group policy Encryption Oracle Remediation default setting from Vulnerable to Mitigated.

Here is [a blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/) written by Micah to give a solutions by editing Local Group Policy.

Hope this helps!