# Windows Azure VM Remote desktop connection issue even from home connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

I created a virtual machine with SQL server 2016 with the free subscription and all the default setting but when i try to **RDP** from home where there is no firewall, i get an **error**(see below). Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to azure VM. CredSSP issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324687/cannot-connect-to-azure-vm-credssp-issue)